# Can't figure out why this small jquery function is recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, append

So I have this small function that simply checks the DOM when a new dynamic piece of HTML is added, and then when the mouse enters an image I want it to append a `<span>` after the image. It works, however it appends like 9 times instead of just once. I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Edit- also, upon each subsequent append action, it appends double the number that it previously did. (So first action it appends 9 times, second action it appends 18 times, etc.)

TIA.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', '.module', function(event) {
  $('.body-copy,.subhead,.lead-in,.blockquote,.disclosure-text,.caption,.link-text,.button,.cta').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
  $('img').mouseenter(function(event) {
     $(this).parent('td').append('<span class="image-link"><a class="fa-link fa"></span>');
     $(this).children('image-link').attr('hover', 'true');
  });
```

});

Comment: You're adding a new `mouseenter` event handler on every image in the DOM (`$('img').mouseenter(...)`) whenever you add an element to any of your `.module` elements (`.on('DOMNodeInserted', '.module', function(event) { ...; $('img').mouseenter(...); })`)

Comment: because with every `DOMNodeInserted` you add another function that adds `span.image-link`. So after the 5th `DOMNodeInserted`, there will be 5 functions adding 5 additional spans.

Comment: Gotcha- so is there a better way to listen for nodes being added to the DOM? I can't get functions to recognize dynamically added elements otherwise, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: _"I can't get functions to recognize dynamically added elements"_ You have already setup an "delegated" event which acts also on dynamically added elements: `.on('DOMNodeInserted', '.module', function(event) { ... })`

Comment: Right, but is there a way to do it so that it isn't executing the function inside that delegated event more than once for the specific object I'm targeting? (The one image I'm rolling over)

Comment: Have a delegated handler for img mouseenter outside your DOMNodeInserted handler, something like `$(document).on('mouseenter', 'img', func);`

Comment: Oh I see- yes that works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's two major parts contributing towards your problem:

1. Your `.on("DOMNodeInserted", ...)` is likely being run more than once.
2. Your `$("img").mouseenter(...)` is running for *every* image on the page, regardless of when it got there.

What's happening is that on each time a DOM node is added to the live tree, that listener is called, including for nodes the listener itself adds.

The correct solution would be to add the event to existing nodes, then adding the same handler to any new `<img>` element added. Something like this:

```
// Factored out the listener for reuse
function listener(e) {
    $(this).parent('td').append('<span class="image-link"><a class="fa-link fa"></span>');
    $(this).children('image-link').attr('hover', 'true');
}

// Add the listener to all existing images.
$('img').on('mouseenter', listener);

// Observe for any future image additions.
new MutationObserver(function (record) {
    $(record.addedNodes).filter('img').on('mouseenter', listener);
    // Avoid memory leaks
    $(record.removedNodes).filter('img').off('mouseenter', listener);
})
.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
});
```

(I'm specifically using MutationObservers because the Mutation Events API has been deprecated for quite some time for performance reasons, and was never completely and interoperably implemented by browsers. Also, MutationObservers have pretty broad compatibility at this point.)